# NSLocalizableString not found my key

Tags: objective-c, ios, nslocalizedstring, localizable.strings

I'm developing iPad international application.
I'm using methods `NSLocalizableString` to translate my application.
I have added keyword manually in my `Localizable.strings` in English and in French named "Orders" with value.
When I call my method `NSLocalizableString` with the keyword, it didn't found my keyword and don't apply the translation.
For keyword above and below, it's working perfectly.

Some code parts :

```
**Localizable.strings**
    /* Change datas */
    "ChangeDatas" =  "Modifier les données";
    /* Orders */
    "Orders" =  "Détails de votre commande";
    /* Label */
    "SomeLabel" =  "Label";
**file.m**
    //Work fine
    NSLog(@"My data translation : %@", NSLocalizedString(@"ChangeDatas", @"Change datas"));
    //Don't work
    NSLog(@"My orders translation : %@", NSLocalizedString(@"Orders", @"Orders"));
```

Comment: Did you try to clean and re-build your app? Also uninstall old version before reinstalling it. I noticed that iPhone tends to cache the localization data somewhere and clean/reinstall might be necessary that it would note the changes.

Comment: I've tried to do that but not success.

Comment: Everything looks fine. Try to control whether you do not have some strange whitespace in your string or if your characters are in the right encoding. Remove and add another string.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your editor was working in the right encoding?  Also, with the correct line endings?

It can't hurt to check your .strings file with the [`plutil`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/plutil.1.html) command.

Are you sure you've edited the .strings file for the same language/locale that you're using at runtime?

Comment: The encoding are UTF16 and the line ending are LR (unix). 
I've tried to user the plutil command and it return OK. I've tried to edit the 2 files( EN & FR ) and nothing change.